# What do all these people have in common?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Some people were gunned down on the frontier a few years back. Their goal of seeking a new life, tragically cut short. Still, they did see some strange things before they died.

Aside from being shot, what did this crew have in common?

There is a well-defined right answer. There are hints in the flavor text. If you get it, you will know that you are right.

```
Carlisle was shot 5 times.
Grant was shot 7 times
Harper was shot once.
Mathews was shot 6 times.
O'Herlihy was shot 3 times.
Rizzo was shot 7 times.
Thompson was shot 10 times.
Unknown was shot 4 times.
Watson was shot 14 times.
```

Comment: Dave, is the below answer correct? If so, please accept it as such!

Comment: Is **Unknown** the *actual* name? Or is it unknown? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the answer has not yet been accepted, I can post a more complete solution here, noting first that for the puzzle to be correct,

> Rizzo should have been shot 7 times instead of 8.

With that in mind, hopefully one of the two answers on this puzzle can be put to bed. (And hopefully this answer can help future puzzlers as well!)

> First, the names need to be put in chronological order by death time. Then, you take the number of times the person was shot, and count that many letters into the title of the episode in which the person was killed.

We see that:

> Mathews was shot 6 times. Episode: "What a**R**e Little Girls Made of?" 
>  O'Herlihy was shot 3 times. Episode: "Ar**E**na" 
>  Unknown was shot 4 times. Episode: "The **D**evil in the Dark" 
>  Grant was shot 7 times. Episode: "Friday'**S** Child" 
>  Carlisle was shot 5 times. Episode: "The C**H**angeling" 
>  Rizzo was shot **7** <strike>8</strike> times. Episode: "Obsess**I**<strike>o</strike>n" 
>  Thompson was shot 10 times. Episode: "By Any Othe**R** Name" 
>  Harper was shot once. Episode: "**T**he Omega Glory" 
>  Watson was shot 14 times. Episode: "Elaan of Troyiu**S**

Then, when you

> put the letters together, you get the word **REDSHIRTS**, which was what all of these individuals were in Star Trek.

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote this; maybe there was a mistake. I'll try to get to it this weekend & review.

Comment: Thanks, @Dave. It was a good puzzle, hoping to give it some closure! :)

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistake. I corrected the puzzle and am accepting your answer.

Comment: It only took 'bout $2\,{}^1/{}_{\,2}$ years or so :D

Answer (score 16):

They were all

> [Star Trek TOS Redshirts who died under Kirk's command](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/database/redshirt_deaths.htm) - For them, space was truly *the final frontier*.

> **LATE EDIT:**
>
>  OK, OP says: "REDSHIRTS: numbers are indexes into the titles; ordering is by stardate & character name. I don't know if that's too obscure for this site; it'd be typical fare at the MIT Mystery Hunt which is where I do most of my puzzling."
>
>  I will admit I don't really understand what this means - Ordered by stardate, using character name (as given in the puzzle) as a secondary ordering criterion, and then treating the episode title as an array, I get nonsense. Switching the ordering order, still nonsense. This is also the case whether I assume the array is 1- or 0-indexed.

Comment: Yes! But can you go one step further? What do the numbers signify?

Comment: @user17625 I'm trying! Please tell me I don't have to watch the episodes to figure it out (not that I don't like ST, I just don't have access to them at the moment)

Comment: No; you don't need to watch them.

Comment: does the 'shot' refer to being shot by a camera perhaps? Signifying the amount of episodes/scenes they were in before they finally got shot in the lethal way?

Comment: @DrunkWolf that occurred to me, but it's not episodes (e.g., Watson would be 1 in this case, or 2 if we're counting appearances of the actor), and minutes/scenes would require watching the show

Comment: @DrunkWolf Addendum: the intro bit uses "gunned down", the 'data' uses "shot", and the reality is that, for example, at least one of them was pushed off a cliff.

Comment: Just a note to others - I looked at the actors that played each part (on IMDB), thinking that maybe the number was a value corresponding to "x number of gigs before being in the show", but that lead nowhere.  In fact, the same actor played both Rizzo and O'Herlihy...

Comment: @APrough yeah, I actually almost noted that in my answer - the numbers can't have significance wrt the actors because of the fact that you mentioned, as well as the fact that "Unknown" is listed among the others.

Comment: Perhaps it's number of camera shots / scenes they appeared in prior to their untimely demises?

Comment: @Hellion See earlier comments - I'm ruling that out due to the fact that you'd have to either a) watch the episodes (which has been stated is not necessary to figure out the answer) or b) know production details that only the people who literally worked on the episode would know.

Comment: @question_asker d'oh!  coulda sworn I'd read the full comment thread.  :-)

Comment: @user17625 You said that one doesn't have to watch the episodes to figure out what the numbers signify. Does this mean that the numbers are not related to things that the characters did in the show, or things that happened to them? (Which would pretty much have to mean that the numbers are somehow related to their names, I think.)

Comment: @SpiritFryer It's been long enough so here's a big hint. You don't need to watch the episodes, but you do need to know their titles & air dates.

Comment: @user17625 I thought of both of those things when I originally posted my answer, but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_casualties_%2823rd_century%29

Comment: @user17625 Whatever the answer is, I'm starting to get the impression it's something really arbitrary, making this more a guessing game than a puzzle.

Comment: @question_asker REDSHIRTS: numbers are indexes into the titles; ordering is by stardate & character name. I don't know if that's too obscure for this site; it'd be typical fare at the MIT Mystery Hunt which is where I do most of my puzzling.

Comment: @user17625 OK so I'll assume you mean "order by stardate" since all stardates and names are unique and as such you can order by one or the other but not both, and I'll assume you're treating the episode titles as arrays. 1-indexed, I get "Ae'CoihT?" (the ? is for Unknown, since they occur in multiple episodes) 0-indexed, I get "rnshnueh?" (see above for ?).

Comment: I ignored everything that wasn't a letter and got "reshosrt?". If the Unknown is from "The Devil in the Dark", it's "redshosrt", which is sort of like "redshirts".